Updates to SQLite DB not seen when running Flutter app in Xcode simulator
A Flutter app, which is running in the Xcode simulator, connects to a SQLite DB.
The DB exists in the folder assets/db, and is referenced in pubspec.yaml as:
assets:
    - assets/db/

The application can access the database. However, after making changes to the DB within VSCode, and restating the application, those changes are not visible.
Closing and restarting the Xcode simulator does not solve the issue.
I have also run
flutter clean
flutter run

to rebuild the Xcode application, but the updated DB is still not getting deployed.
The problem also exists when running the application on a physical iPhone using:
flutter run --release

I can verify this within the app using the following code:
db = await openDatabaseFromAssets('my_db.db');
print(await db.query("my_table")); 

What is printed to the terminal is the state of the table before the changes.
The only solution so far is to change the name of the DB. But then the same problem exists with the renamed DB when data is subsequently changed. In other words, the DB is only being copied across to the build once.
Could anyone assist, thanks
